# Use of ARG variables from Dockerfile in a python file which is inside the container built from the docker file

Tags: docker

I have 2 values:

- `ARG USERNAME`
- `ARG PASSKEY`

I built the `dockerfile` and is running the image successfully. In a Python file (inside the docker image), needs to use those username and passkey values.

Comment: What do you have so far?  What problems are you encountering?  You almost never want to pass credentials as `ARG`, since anyone who has the image can later extract them; passing them in as environment variables or in a mounted file is usually a better approach.

Comment: As of now, I'm sending the credentials a ARG, my problem is I want them to use them later inside my container in a python script like that.